# How to enable Location Services for a WKWebView in Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview, location-services

My Browser app uses WKWebView but when I try to visit a website that needs to use Location Services (like Google Maps, for example), it doesn't work.

I have searched for a way to fix it and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019946/wkwebview-with-location-services). I tried to add the string on the answer to the question to my Info.plist but it doesn't resolve the issue.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,

PastaCoder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how, but trying to add a string for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in the Info.plist did work yesterday and the issue has been resolved.